# Group by on text column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Do group by on text columns works?

In following query, subquery return a medium text column(empcode).
Group by on this empcode column is returning incorrect result.

```
SELECT mgr_code,empcode,GROUP_CONCAT(date)date
FROM 
(
    SELECT date, mgr_code, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT empcode ORDER BY empcode) empcode
    FROM table
    GROUP BY mgr_code,date
)
GROUP BY mgr_code,empcode
```

Is something wrong with the query or group by on text column do not work?

Comment: Yes. They work just fine. If that doesn't completely answer your question, See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the expected answer, what data does it contain. Provide a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think your query alone is not sufficient for us to know exactly what you are trying to do.  It may be correct, or it may not be, that would depend on your data, which you never showed us.

Comment: which means bad results? Any example result?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no wrong in your query.

You can use **`GROUP BY`** with **`TEXT`** field